# ASP.NET Application - Accessing details about a drop down list's DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding

I have the following markup:

```
   <td>
      <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlExtRouteBusyID" style="width: 320px;" />
   </td>
```

And code behind that executes on page load:

```
//Bind the route busy drop down list:
DataTable dr = /*[some DataTable returned from a wrapper to an RDBMS*/;
this.ddlExtRouteBusyID.DataSource = dt;
this.ddlExtRouteBusyID.DataTextField = "description";
this.ddlExtRouteBusyID.DataValueField = "id";
this.ddlExtRouteBusyID.DataBind();
```

I cannot seem to access the description and ID data based upon the value of the SelectedItem/Value.  For example if I select the second list item, the SelectedIndex is 1, but the description might be "server2" and the ID might be 1118.  How can I pull the description and ID values?

Thanks.

Comment: In Page_Load, are you checking for IsPostBack?

Comment: Your original comment was correct.  I simply overlooked the very basic SelectedValue field.  If it were an answer I'd mark it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to get the text and the value:

```
ddlExtRouteBusyID.SelectedItem.Text
ddlExtReouteBusyID.SelectedItem.Value
```

If this doesn't work there may be some other problem with what the page is doing, since I just verified that these worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things not cleared in question, so here are some of the Options I thought about..

1) If you want to access value and text client side you can use simple **JQUERY** as follows..

```
$("#ddlExtRouteBusyID.ClientID").change(function() {
   selectval();
});
$("#ddlExtRouteBusyID.ClientID").click(function() {
   selectval();    
});

function selectval(){
   alert('Text:' + $('#ddlExtRouteBusyID.ClientID :selected').text() + ', value = ' + $("#ddlExtRouteBusyID.ClientID").val());    
}
```

2) Use the values on server side then **HOW?**, I mean **onSelectedIndexChange** or On Any **ButtonClick** event

Note : to use any way the dropdownlist databind method should be kept in **if(!IsPostBack)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add two properties to your `DropDownList` definition, `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `AutoPostBack`, like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlExtRouteBusyID" style="width: 320px;" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Now you need to write code in your code-behind to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, like this:

```
protected void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // Put logic here to grab values from drop down list
   Label1.Text = "You selected " + ddlExtRouteBusyID.SelectedItem.Text +
                 " with a value of " + ddlExtRouteBusyID.SelectedItem.Value +
                 ".";
}
```

Note: `AutoPostBack=true` is what causes the page to post back to the server when the drop down list value changes; otherwise the drop down list change event will not fire.